# Impossible to access docker private registry on gitlab

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, docker-compose, gitlab

I'm trying to set Continuous integration with gitlab and a private docker registry.
I've followed the whole tutorials to set it up, I managed to set the registry tab on the left in a project environment but when I click on this tab, gitlab brings me immediately an error 500.

I use gitlab as a docker container, a private registry as another container.
I Have to edit the gitlab.yml file? I think this problem is caused by a certificate.

here are my logs located on : `/var/log/gitlab/gitlab/production.log`

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /certs/registry.key):
lib/json_web_token/rsa_token.rb:20:in `read'
lib/json_web_token/rsa_token.rb:20:in `key_data'
lib/json_web_token/rsa_token.rb:24:in `key'
lib/json_web_token/rsa_token.rb:28:in `public_key'
lib/json_web_token/rsa_token.rb:33:in `kid'
lib/json_web_token/rsa_token.rb:12:in `encoded'
app/services/auth/container_registry_authentication_service.rb:31:in `full_access_token'
app/models/container_repository.rb:13:in `registry'
app/models/container_repository.rb:7:in `client'
app/models/container_repository.rb:36:in `manifest'
app/models/container_repository.rb:41:in `tags'
app/models/container_repository.rb:53:in `has_tags?'
app/controllers/projects/registry/repositories_controller.rb:48:in `block (2 levels) in ensure_root_container_repository!'
app/controllers/projects/registry/repositories_controller.rb:47:in `tap'
app/controllers/projects/registry/repositories_controller.rb:47:in `block in ensure_root_container_repository!'
app/controllers/projects/registry/repositories_controller.rb:44:in `tap'
app/controllers/projects/registry/repositories_controller.rb:44:in `ensure_root_container_repository!'
lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:47:in `with_locale'
lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:53:in `with_user_locale'
 app/controllers/application_controller.rb:337:in `set_locale'
lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:93:in `call'
lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:14:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:17:in `call'
lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:11:in `call'
lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only.rb:30:in `call'
lib/gitlab/request_context.rb:18:in `call'
lib/gitlab/metrics/requests_rack_middleware.rb:27:in `call'
```

Thanks for helping me, I've been stuck here for 1 month, (i'm a rookie in docker and CI)

Thanks for your help,

Grtz,

Tom

Comment: Did you find a solution?